# Create new matrices from the comparison of two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, comparison

I have two matrices `X1` and `X2` representing the complex solution of a polynom:

```
X1=(N.t[:,1,1]-N.t[:,0,0]-np.sqrt(delta))/2*(N.t[:,1,0])
X2=(N.t[:,1,1]-N.t[:,0,0]+np.sqrt(delta))/2*(N.t[:,1,0])
```

I'm trying to create two new matrices `C1` and `C2`: `C1` must contains the maximum values: `max(X1, X2)` and `C2` must contains the minimum values: `min(X1, X2)`. I used `np.abs` to compare the values since they are complex but I don't know how to make the indexation.

May someone could help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare complexe numbers, you first need to "convert" them to real ones using their absolute values :

```
X1_real, X2_real  = np.abs(X1), np.abs(X2)
```

Then, you can simply use numpy's [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function, as follows :

```
boolean_array = (X1_real >= X2_real) # Or >, as you want.

C1 = np.where(boolean_array, X1, X2) # If X1_real[i] is >= X2_real[i], then C1[i] will be equal to X1[i], otherwise to X2[i].
C2 = np.where(boolean_array, X2, X1) # The opposite here.
```

This matches the maximum and minimum arrays you seek !

Comment: Great! I didn't think of using a boolean variable!

Comment: @DODO if this answer fits you, I'd be glad you validate it please ;)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this.